# Redirect loop in urlrewrite (Tomcat)

Tags: tomcat, redirect, https, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I'm implementing a redirect in Tomcat with urlrewite filter to force https in a page, but the rule I created is causing a redirect loop.

This is the rule:

```
<rule match-type="wildcard">
    <condition type="scheme" operator="notequal">https</condition>
    <condition name="host" operator="equal">www.example.net</condition>
    <from>/en/page-name/</from>
    <to type="permanent-redirect" last="true">https://www.example.net/context/en/page-name/</to>
</rule>
```

Can someone help me? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Your conditions :

```
<condition type="scheme" operator="notequal">https</condition>
<condition name="host" operator="equal">www.example.net</condition>
<from>/en/page-name/</from>
```

means it shouldn't start with https but the host should be equal to www.example.net.

Your redirect :

```
https://www.example.net/context/en/page-name/
```

start with https. You get redirected to this page, you dont match the condition, get redirected to this page etc.

Comment: Okay, I understand what you say, but my problem is that, apparently, the redirection is ignoring this condition:

<condition type="scheme" operator="notequal">https</condition>

I think that if the redirection doesn't ignore that condition, no loop should occur. I don't understand why ingores this.

Thank you very much for your help.